# Logging Oracle Java Stored Procedure using Java Logging API (java.util.logging )

Tags: java, oracle, logging, stored-procedures, oracle10g

I've developed a new Java(1.4) Stored Procedure in Oracle (10g). I've never done this before, I usually keep Java and the DB separated but this was a requisite. So I developed a Java code that can be deployed in Tomcat as well as a Stored Procedure in Oracle. For this I used the Java Logging API.

I can execute the stored procedure in Oracle, but I can't find the logs. I would like to know what should I do in order to print the logs, it can be to Oracle logs or trc files, or even, if possible, configure it to print the logs to another specific folder.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: It seems that you can configure the logging.properties, check the latest answer of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665984/how-to-debug-java-stored-procedures-in-oracle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As appointed by PeskyGnat in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665984/how-to-debug-java-stored-procedures-in-oracle) you have to create a logging.properties file in the folder:

> $ORACLE_HOME/javavm/lib

After you configure this file, you can see the logs in:

> $ORACLE_BASE/admin/$INSTANCE/udump

In my case, this was Solaris so the first path was:

> /export/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/Db_1/javavm/lib

And the second one:

> /export/home/oracle/app/oracle/admin/

---

---

**As extra information, in order to make easy to find the log file you can type in Bash shell the following:**

```
ls -altr
```

And this is an example of how the logging.properties file:

```
############################################################
#   Default Logging Configuration File
#
# You can use a different file by specifying a filename
# with the java.util.logging.config.file system property.  
# For example java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=myfile
############################################################
############################################################
#   Global properties
############################################################
# "handlers" specifies a comma separated list of log Handler 
# classes.  These handlers will be installed during VM startup.
# Note that these classes must be on the system classpath.
# By default we only configure a ConsoleHandler, which will only
# show messages at the INFO and above levels.
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
# To also add the FileHandler, use the following line instead.
#handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
# Default global logging level.
# This specifies which kinds of events are logged across
# all loggers.  For any given facility this global level
# can be overriden by a facility specific level
# Note that the ConsoleHandler also has a separate level
# setting to limit messages printed to the console.
.level= INFO
############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################
# default file output is in user's home directory.
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = %h/java%u.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.XMLFormatter
# Limit the message that are printed on the console to INFO and above.
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

# For example, set the com.xyz.foo logger to only log SEVERE
# messages:
**<your.class.logger>.level = <level> (i.e.: INFO)**
```