# Oracle Database console logs

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have Java stored procedures with writing to java.util.logging INFO and ERROR levels. My logging.properties of Oracle Database is pretty much default - only ConsoleHandler is configured on INFO level.

Database was started with SQL*PLUS `sqlplus startup open`. So the question is: where to find my logging info if database started like that (no nohup output)? alert logs are not sufficient as there is no such output at all.

Thanks.

Comment: then you need to setup an appended to a file, no?

Comment: Possibly in a trace file, [like system output](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDEV/chseven.htm#JJDEV13282)?

Comment: @OldProgrammer yes we need that, and now we've done that. but there was procedures that works 3 years + so now: when some of them broken we need that exactly logs comeout from the error.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not seeing what broken procedures have to do with logging the database startup command. What information do you want to capture?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson the logging information from procedure.

Comment: Is this the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652097/logging-oracle-java-stored-procedure-using-java-logging-api-java-util-logging

Comment: It appears to be documented here: [Logging in Oracle JVM](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDEV/chtwo.htm#JJDEV13565)